# Postgres Crosstab allocating values to wrong columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a sample table named antest as shown below to test the crosstab function.

```
create table antest(student text, subject text, result numeric);
insert into antest(student, subject, result) values
('peter','music',2.0), 
('peter','language',2.0),
('gabriel','history',8.0),
('john','history',9.0),
('john','maths',4.0),
('john','music',7.0);

student|subject|result
-------+-------+------
peter  |music  |2.0
peter  |lanuage|2.0
gabriel|history|8.0
john   |history|9.0
john   |maths  |4.0
john   |music  |7.0
```

Result wanted:

```
student|music|language|history|maths
-------+-----+--------+-------+-----
peter  |2.0  |2.0     |       |
gabriel|     |        |8.0    |
john   |7.0  |        |9.0    |4.0
```

I have executed the follwoin query for that:

```
select * 
from public.crosstab (
    'select student, subject, result from antest',
    'select distinct subject from antest'
) as final_result(student text, music numeric, maths numeric, history numeric, language numeric);
```

I got the following result:

```
student|music|maths|history|language
-------+-----+-----+-------+--------
peter  |2.0  |     |       |2.0
gabriel|     |8.0  |       |
john   |7.0  |9.0  |4.0    |
```

Kindly let me know the mistake I am doing.

I have to repeat this query for anyother database which is 30gb large later with about 75 attributes. Is there any possibility to automate it?

Comment: Please post `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` to recreate your case

Comment: @Iad2025 edited the question. and the result is not even with ORDER BY 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to take care that the order of categories is exactly the same in the category query and in the column definition. Because you want an arbitrary chosen (not alphabetical) order, you should use `values` in the category query.

```
select * 
from crosstab (
    $q$ select student, subject, result from antest $q$,
    $q$ values ('music'), ('language'), ('history'), ('maths') $q$
) as final_result(student text, music numeric, language numeric, history numeric, maths numeric);


 student | music | language | history | maths 
---------+-------+----------+---------+-------
 peter   |   2.0 |      2.0 |         |      
 gabriel |       |          |     8.0 |      
 john    |   7.0 |          |     9.0 |   4.0
(3 rows)
```

Of course, you can use `order by` in the query but then you have to change the order in the column definition:

```
select * 
from crosstab (
    $q$ select student, subject, result from antest $q$,
    $q$ select distinct subject from antest order by 1 $q$
) as final_result(student text, history numeric, language numeric, math numeric, music numeric);

 student | history | language | math | music 
---------+---------+----------+------+-------
 peter   |         |      2.0 |      |   2.0
 gabriel |     8.0 |          |      |      
 john    |     9.0 |          |  4.0 |   7.0
(3 rows)
```

Comment: This worked thanks. What if I want it in alphabetic order and for about 75 attributes?

Comment: Understood. All of them should basically be in the alphabetical order if want it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -3):

Telmo, Portugal, hospital Aveiro: same problem today; never used crosstab(), only case when; it works fine

Comment: what works fine?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).